# Should I write this release?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

-- example.h --

```
@property ( copy ) NSString *string;
@property ( retain ) Object *object;

-- example.m --
( void ) do {
    // I have used 'string' and 'object' using their setter method several times.
}

( void ) dealloc {
    [ string release ]; // Should I write this code?
    [ object release ]; // Should I write this code?
}
```

They didn't use alloc, copy, new.
But they are pointing latest objects that were made in their setter method and not released.
I really want to know about this situations though it is not very important.

Comment: Don’t forget to send `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Did you `@synthesize` these instance variables?

Comment: This question is a summary. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You did not `@synthesize` these `@property`s, so your code will not work.** - Add a `@synthesize` directive like so:

```
@synthesize string, object;
```

Yes, you should send them the `release` message in `-dealloc` in this case, because you're using `copy` and `retain`, which both obtain ownership of the receiver.

```
- (void) dealloc {
   [string release];
   [object release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

**ALSO DO NOT FORGET TO INVOKE `[super dealloc]` AT THE BOTTOM OF YOUR `-dealloc` METHOD!!**

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should release both in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because your `NSString *string` is a `copy` property and your `NSObject *object` is a `retain` property. By using their setters, your instance copies and retains the objects you assign to them respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Because you `@synthesized` your properties, remember assigning the property to `nil` will release it for you, *and* ensure that code cannot continue to use it.

```
- (void) dealloc {
  string = nil;
  object = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

If you had instance variables (iVars), then you should use `release` since there is no setter accessor that will release it for you.